# why does xmlHttpRequest.Open only work when I input a string?

Tags: javascript, restful-url

I'm trying to call a Restful service on my localhost. I am doing it this way because It's an asynchronous call. The appropriate Url plus the Uri-template to call my service is this:

"http://localhost:65016/Service1.svc/SN?lower=200&upper=300"

on the line where I try to open ( xhttp.open ), my client page only receives the proper data whenever I literally insert the url like this:

```
xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:65016/Service1.svc/SN?lower=200&upper=300" , true);
```

but I need the 200 and 300 numbers to be user input so I tried these two things: 
I first tried grabbing the user input and simply concatenating it to the base URL in between the URi template like this:

```
    <script>
        function ServiceCall()
        {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
            {
                if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                    var ans = document.getElementById("secretNum");
                    ans.innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
                }

            }
            var base_uri = "http://localhost:65016/Service1.svc/";

            // grab the lower number
            var ln = document.getElementById("LN").firstChild;
            var LN = ln.nodeValue;

            // grab upper number
            var un = document.getElementById("UN").firstChild;
            var UN = un.nodeValue;

            //complete
            var URL = base_uri + "SN?lower=" + LN + "&upper=" + UN;

            xhttp.open("GET", URL, true);
            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            xhttp.send();
        }
</script>
```

Doesn't work. So i tried looking at the documentation for the xmlHttpRequest.open, and I saw that the parameter had to be a URL. so I tried using the URL(string) function and using the output as a parameter and that didn't work either. 
Any help please?

Comment: Use the debugging tools in your browser. See what network requests are being made. And console.log the URL variable to see its true value.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I it helped to look at the network request. I was simply using the wrong syntax to obtain the value inside of the html input tag.

```
var ln = document.getElementById("LN").value;
```

returns the real value inside of html input tag given by the user input. 
I'm answering my own question because this is a homework assignment. 
(Not that I was cheating. Answering this is far from solving the homework)

Comment: Nice that you got it to work :) Using the dev tools to find problems is how the pros do it, so getting experience with that is useful!